# Modulus operation for array index

Tags: java, arrays, modulus

I got a tutorial about using a button for switching some images, and here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static ImageView andro;
private static Button buttonswitch;

int current_image_index = 0;
int[] images = {R.mipmap.andro_img,R.mipmap.apple_image,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonClick();
}
public void buttonClick() {
    andro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    buttonswitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonswitch.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    current_image_index++;
                    current_image_index = current_image_index % images.length;
                    andro.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

I got really confused in this part :

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                current_image_index++;
                current_image_index = current_image_index % images.length;
                andro.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
```

What I understand is that once I click the button, then the int current_image_index will increase by 1. Then modulus current_image_index with the images.length which will have the remainder of current_image_index divide by the image.length. For example, for the first time I will have current_image_index = 0, then once clicked, it will be 1, then current_image_index % image.length = 0. Then andro.setImageResource(images[0]);

this will repeated again and again since the current_image_index stays to be 0. Then how can the picture changes constantly once it is clicked since the current_image_index%image.length will always give a result of 0.

Comment: You say "it will be 1, then current_image_index % image.length = 0". This is incorrect; `image.length` is 4, so `current_image_index` 0 gives 0, 1 gives 1, 2 gives 2, 3 gives 3 then **4 gives 0**, thus you get your wrapping round.

Comment: It's incrementing the image counter.  Instead of them using a conditional to check if you've gone past the, the modulo value automatically resets to zero once you've gone past the end.

Comment: Basic Mathematics - answer of `a%b` is always  `<b`. Incrementing by 1 and taking modulus ensures that the increased value forms a valid index for the array.

Comment: I think you don't understand what modulo is doing.  1 modulo 5, for example, is 1, not 0.

Comment: @KenY-N why 1 gives 1 ? 2 gives 2 ? And so on... Isnt that modulo is the remainder of division ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *...since the current_image_index%image.length will always give a result of 0.*

**Not quite correct.**

The modulus operator (`%`) calculates the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) of two operands. It is a sort of repeated subtraction. In fact, with `a % b` you'll ask yourself:

> *What number remains if I repeat subtracting `b` from `a` until that operation is no longer possible?*

Let us test it with `8 % 3` (so `a = 8` and `b = 3`).

- Can I subtract 3 from 8? Yes, result is 5.
- Can I subtract 3 from 5? Yes, result is 2.
- Can I subtract 3 from 2? **No, so our final result is 2**.

Logically, the operation `a % b` with result `r` always results in  `0 <= r < b`.

> **Examples:**
> 5 % 2 = 1 (because 4 ÷ 2 = 2 and the remainder is 1)
> 17 % 6 = 5 (because 12 ÷ 6 = 2 and the remainder is 5)
> 20 % 4 = 0 (because 20 ÷ 4 = 5 and nothing remains)

So in your case, the array index is always at least `0` and at most `images.length - 1`. And that's exactly the valid range of your array.

Suppose you have **3** images, thus `images.length` is **3**. Also `current_image_index` is initialized to **0**. So you'll see `image[0]` at the beginning.

1. You click once, so `current_image_index` is incremented to `1`. Then, the modulus operation is applied: `1 % 3 = 1`.
2. You click again, so `current_image_index` is incremented to `2`. Then, the modulus operation is applied: `2 % 3 = 2`.
3. You click again, so `current_image_index` is incremented to `3`. Then, the modulus operation is applied: `3 % 3 = 0`. That means the index reached **3**, but then was immediately reset to **0** by the modulus operator.

So after `image[2]`, `image[0]` is shown. You see that indices starting at 0 instead of 1 is working in our benefit now.

Answer (score 0):

`current_image_index % images.length` works as a module.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

So I think we both a agree  `1/2 = 0 R 1`.

And modulo in every programming language means simply take the remainder of the division and return it as the result of the operation.

So `1 ‰ 2 = 1` and not zero.